# Groovy: How do I evaluate expression which has functions inside Java code?

Tags: java, groovy

Here's my sample expression:

```
foo("hello") + bar("world")
```

I am using groovy (2.0.5) as an expression parser so don't want to define functions (foo and bar) in groovy but would rather like to get notified as Java calls when the expression is parsed. I suppose this can be done by using one of the flavors of meta class. Unfortunately I tried all combinations but my implementation of meta class (i.e., MyExpandoMetaClass's invokeMissingMethod) never get called.

Any help is appreciated.

Sample Java Code:

```
MetaClassRegistryImpl.getInstance(0).setMetaClass(Script.class, new MyExpandoMetaClass());

String expression = "foo(\"hello\") + bar (\"world\")";
Binding binding = new Binding();
Script script = new GroovyShell(binding).parse(expression);
assertEquals("helloworld", script.evaluate(expression));
```

...

```
class MyExpandoMetaClass extends ExpandoMetaClass {
    public MyExpandoMetaClass() {
        super(Script.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public Object invokeMissingMethod(Object instance, String methodName, Object[] arguments) {
        if (("foo".equals(methodName) || "bar".equals(methodName)) {
            return arguments[0];
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.foo() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hello]
Possible solutions: run(), run(), find(), any(), is(java.lang.Object), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:518)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:556)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:527)
    at groovy.lang.Script.evaluate(Script.java:208)
    at com.barcap.edt.amd.analytics.operation.postprocess.ExpressionParserTest.function(ExpressionParserTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you cannot use metaClass or related Groovy functionality from Java at all.  It is simply not supported and will not work

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2011/11/groovy-goodness-create-our-own-script.html) is an example of using [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) with a CompilerConfiguration, which may be useful.

Using Groovy 2.0.5, this code:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

abstract class FooBarScript extends Script {
    def foo(def x) { 
        println "hello from foo"
        return x 
    }

    def bar(def x) { 
        println "hello from bar" 
        return x 
    }
}

def compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration()
compilerConfiguration.scriptBaseClass = FooBarScript.class.name

def binding = new Binding()

def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, binding, compilerConfiguration)

String expression = "foo(\"hello\") + bar (\"world\")"

def result = shell.evaluate expression
println result
```

gives this output:

```
hello from foo
hello from bar
helloworld
```

Given that the original post requested Java, the script can be moved to the following Java class:

```
import groovy.lang.Script;

public class FooBarScript extends Script {
    public String foo(String x) {
        System.out.println("hello from foo");
        return x;
    }

    public String bar(String x) {
        System.out.println("hello from bar");
        return x;
    }

    public Object run() { return null; }
}
```

where this can simply be imported into the Groovy example

Comment: Thanks Michael. Like I said, I don't want to define foo and bar inside groovy but within Java itself (I can even call foo/bar Java methods myself as long as I get call back with method name and arguments while expression is evaluated). Do you happen to know?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal here, but I've updated the answer to show how the script can be written in Java. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The complete Java solution of Micheal's answer is following:

1.Write Groovy script with Java(the same as Micheal's answer):

```
import groovy.lang.Script;

public class FooBarScript extends Script {
    public String foo(String x) {
        System.out.println("hello from foo");
        return x;
    }

    public String bar(String x) {
        System.out.println("hello from bar");
        return x;
    }

    public Object run() { return null; }
}
```

2.Call the methods defined in FooBarScript.java:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration;

public class Main {
    private static final GroovyShell shell;

    static {
        CompilerConfiguration cfg = new CompilerConfiguration();
        cfg.setScriptBaseClass(FooBarScript.class.getName());
        shell = new GroovyShell(cfg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expression = "println(foo('hello') + bar ('world'))";
        Script script = shell.parse(expression);
        script.run();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
hello from foo
hello from bar
helloworld
```